# Trying to build android APK with buildozer and cant find Jinja2

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

So I have a kivyMD program that I am trying to build into an Android APK using Buildozer for 2 days now. I have followed tutorials, videos, and documentation but I keep going around in circles.

so running the `sudo buildozer android debug` command inside my VEnv I get this:

```
(venv) beb@pop-os:~/PycharmProjects/$ sudo buildozer android debug
# Check configuration tokens
Buildozer is running as root!
This is not recommended, and may lead to problems later.
Are you sure you want to continue [y/n]? y
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run ['git', 'config', '--get', 'remote.origin.url']
# Cwd /home/beb/PycharmProjects/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git
# Run ['git', 'branch', '-vv']
# Cwd /home/beb/PycharmProjects/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
* develop 4ebd3a87 [origin/develop] Fix `vlc` recipe build (#2841)
# Run ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-q', '--user', 'appdirs', 'colorama>=0.3.3', 'jinja2', 'sh>=1.10, <2.0; sys_platform!="nt"', 'build', 'toml', 'packaging']
# Cwd None
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
# Apache ANT found at /root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
# Recommended android's NDK version by p4a is: 25b
# Android NDK found at /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b
# Run ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'aab', '-h', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/home/beb/PycharmProjects/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# Cwd /home/beb/PycharmProjects/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[WARNING]: prerequisites.py is experimental and does not support all prerequisites yet.
[WARNING]: Please report any issues to the python-for-android issue tracker.
ERROR: The jinja2 Python module could not be found, please install it.
python-for-android is exiting due to the errors logged above
# This buildozer version requires a python-for-android version with AAB (Android App Bundle) support. Please update your pinned version accordingly.
# Check configuration tokens
#
```

doing a pip show for Jinja2 give this

```
(venv) beb@pop-os:~/PycharmProjects/$ pip show jinja2
Name: Jinja2
Version: 3.1.2
Summary: A very fast and expressive template engine.
Home-page: https://palletsprojects.com/p/jinja/
Author: Armin Ronacher
Author-email: armin.ronacher@active-4.com
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: /home/beb/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: MarkupSafe
Required-by:
```

doing a pip show for python-for-android gives nothing inside the VEnv but in the full system gives this:

```
beb@pop-os:~$ pip show python-for-android
Name: python-for-android
Version: 2023.5.21
Summary: Android APK packager for Python scripts and apps
Home-page: https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android
Author: The Kivy team
Author-email: kivy-dev@googlegroups.com
License: MIT
Location: /home/beb/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: appdirs, colorama, jinja2, packaging, pep517, sh, toml
Required-by: 
beb@pop-os:~$
```

I cant seem to install it in the VEnv. I've tried manually installing from the git in the VEnv, but I keep getting the same error.

here is the pip freeze form inside the VEnv that also has all the modules for the Python Kivy app:

```
(venv) beb@pop-os:~/PycharmProjects$ pip freeze
appdirs==1.4.4
bcrypt==4.0.1
build==0.10.0
buildozer==1.5.0
certifi==2023.5.7
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
colorama==0.4.6
Cython==0.29.33
distlib==0.3.6
docutils==0.20.1
filelock==3.12.2
idna==3.4
Jinja2==3.1.2
Kivy==2.2.0
Kivy-examples==2.2.0
Kivy-Garden==0.1.5
kivymd @ file:///home/beb/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/KivyMD
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
materialyoucolor==1.2.0
mysql-connector==2.2.9
packaging==23.1
pep517==0.13.0
pexpect==4.8.0
Pillow==9.5.0
platformdirs==3.8.1
ptyprocess==0.7.0
Pygments==2.15.1
pyproject_hooks==1.0.0
requests==2.31.0
sh==1.14.3
toml==0.10.2
tomli==2.0.1
urllib3==2.0.3
virtualenv==20.23.1
```

Can anyone help?

I am on linux using Popos and python  3.10.6
Thanks